# PHP string, how to get field name or value

Tags: php, json

I have a several  data strings, for example:

```
$string1='["message":"hello"]';
$string2='["error":"wrong"]';
```

And what i want to do here is to check field names, something like:
if $string1 field name is error then echo "wrong", but if $string1 field name is message then do something else. How would this look in php code?
i just want to understand how can i get field names and values. Thank you.

Comment: That's not json. JSON should look like `$string1='{"message":"hello"}';`.

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. - also just asking for code w/o showing effort.

Comment: `explode()` and `trim()` are all you need here.

Comment: @jeroen: or just good old sscanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have json string you can use json_decode to parse the string and get it in an array

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$string1 = '{"message":"hello"}';
$string2 = '{"error":"wrong"}';

$data1 = json_decode($string1, true);
$data2 = json_decode($string2, true);

echo $data1['message']; //outputs hello
echo $data2['error']; //outputs wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You could juste decode the json string and then access the data as native php variables and test them as such.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php